# Уменьшение div со всеми вложенными элементами пропорционально экрану

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо при уменьшении окна браузера, уменьшать главный div пропорционально и при этом, чтобы все вложенные div и картинки уменьшались также пропорционально без сдвига.
У меня стоит главная картинка **2.png** на которой находятся определённые элементы, которые смещать нельзя.

Код:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute;"><img src="../images/2.png"/></div>
    <div style="position: absolute;right: 5px;top: 155px;"><img src="../views/vid/images/f.png"/></div>
<ul class="bt-nut" style="position: absolute;right: 5px;top: 155px;">
        <li>
            <a href="" class="link-desc">
                <div class="ch-item2" style="background:url(../images/wt.jpg) center center no-repeat;top: 154px;right: 20px;"> 
                    <div class="ch-info-wrap2">
                        <div class="ch-info2">
                            <div class="ch-info-front2" style="background:url(../images/wt.jpg) center center no-repeat;"></div>
                            <div class="ch-info-back2" style="background:url(../images/wt.jpg) center center no-repeat;">
                                <div>
                                    <div>

                                        <span class="sp2"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a> 
        </li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может пора вместо масштабирования заниматься адаптивной версткой страниц?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V я пишу сайт на bootstrap, но выполнить именно этот момент не получается на нём. Наложение на картинку множества элементов в разных местах без смещения не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы противник использования "благ" адаптивной верстки, то попробуйте использовать (пример на LESS):

```
.transform(@transformation) {
    /* @alternate */ -webkit-transform: @transformation;
    /* @alternate */ -moz-transform: @transformation;
    /* @alternate */ -o-transform: @transformation;
    /* @alternate */ -ms-transform: @transformation;
    transform: @transformation;
}

.transform-origin(@x: 0, @y: 0, @z: 0) {
    -webkit-transform-origin: @x @y @z;
    -moz-transform-origin: @x @y @z;
    -o-transform-origin: @x @y @z;
    -ms-transform-origin: @x @y @z;
    transform-origin: @x @y @z;
}

@media (max-width: 776px) {
    .obj1 {
        .transform-origin(center, top);
        .transform(scale(0,5));
    }
}
```

Таких блоков у Вас будет много, но для разной ширины экрана. При этом учитывайте относительно какого угла масштабировать.

Например если `style="position: absolute;right: 5px;top: 155px;"`, то масштабировать следует относительно правого верхнего угла - `.transform-origin(right, top);`.

Если не знакомы с LESS а Вам нужен css, то считайте что `.transform(@transformation)` и `.transform-origin(@x: 0, @y: 0, @z: 0)` функции которые подставят свое тело в Ваши меди запросы.

Comment: Спасибо. Не особо понял. не могу разобраться. Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, показать на примере. У меня на главную картинку накладывается еще картинка (дерево), а на дерево уже накладываются другие картинки (к примеру). При уменьшении экрана главная картинка уменьшается, дерево с наложенными картинками не уменьшается, дерево и картинки наложенные обёрнуты в div.

Comment: Главная картинка (фон) уменьшается за счет max-width:100%;